# Filling area Or geting area under the Surface using ManimCE

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, manim, algorithm-animation

[image: I want Plot this figure by using ManimCE]
the equation of the surface of the given image[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yP5z.png) is Sin[x+y^2]. I Want to plot similler figure in ManimCE. I Plot this figure using wolfram mathemaitca. Mathematica code given following -

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   RegionFunction -> (#1^2 + #2^2 < 4 &), Filling -> Bottom, 
   FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.4], Red]]
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Surface](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.three_d.three_dimensions.Surface.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

```
from manim import *
```

class SinXYPlot3D(ThreeDScene):
def construct(self):
axes = ThreeDAxes(
x_range=[-2, 2, 0.5],
y_range=[-2, 2, 0.5],
z_range=[-1, 1, 0.5],
x_length=7,
y_length=7,
z_length=4
)

```
    def func(x, y):
        return np.sin(x + y**2)
    
    def condition(x, y):
        return x**2 + y**2 < 4

    surface = Surface(
        lambda u, v: axes.c2p(u, v, func(u, v)),
        u_range=[-2, 2],
        v_range=[-2, 2],
        checkerboard_colors=[BLUE_D, BLUE_E],
        resolution=(50, 50)
    ).set_opacity(0.5)  # Set the opacity for the filling effect

    # Filter out the parts of the surface that don't meet the condition
    surface_filtered = Surface(
        lambda u, v: axes.c2p(u, v, func(u, v) if condition(u, v) else np.nan),
        u_range=[-2, 2],
        v_range=[-2, 2],
        checkerboard_colors=[BLUE_D, BLUE_E],
        resolution=(50, 50)
    ).set_opacity(0.5)

    self.set_camera_orientation(phi=75 * DEGREES, theta=30 * DEGREES)
    self.add(axes, surface_filtered)
    self.wait()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).